# EAS build delayed by Fastlane search for devices

Tags: xcode, expo, fastlane, eas

During `eas build` I get the message:

```
[RUN_FASTLANE] $ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./learning.xcworkspace -scheme learning -configuration Debug
[RUN_FASTLANE] --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
[RUN_FASTLANE] { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
[RUN_FASTLANE] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
```

followed by a long list of iOS devices. I git this several times in a row, each of which consumes time and slows down my builds.

Specifically, I'm running

```
eas build --profile development --platform ios --local --clear-cache
```

on macOS.

How do I get rid of this step in the build process?